# DateValue function and Group By: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Access 2010 and have a table like the following called `Table1` (the table is imported from Excel and the date column was formatted as `date` there):

```
date                      xy
---------------------------------
19.10.2016 14:10:51       jljh
19.10.2016 13:13:28       kgkhg
19.10.2016 12:53:15       asd
```

I've already accepted that I can't do normal SQL things in Access. But why does the following simple-as-hell query ends in the error `data type mismatch in criteria expression`?

```
SELECT DateValue(DATE) as dt, COUNT(CSID)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateValue(DATE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You -- that is me -- say that the table was imported from Excel. So go back to Excel, do the date truncation there, re-import it again, and your -- that is my -- query will run as if it were "normal" SQL. Nothing more intuitive than this shit.

**EDIT:** Meanwhile I also figured out what the problem was: there were unfilled values in the date column. So `DateValue` cannot know how to handle them and must throw an exception. However, what's still a bit annoying is that this error did not occur without the `group by` statement. So it's only 50% the blame of Access this time, the other part is on me :-)

Comment: OK, that explains. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

First, you *can* do "normal SQL things" in Access.

Then, *DateValue* doesn't accept *dot* as the date separator, thus:

```
SELECT DateValue(Replace([DATE], ".", "/")) as dt, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateValue(Replace([DATE], ".", "/"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work (I would wonder if, because I've imported it from Excel as a date field, so the representation on screen shouldn't matter). And it's not normal imo, because without the `group by`, everything works fine. It's perverted. Ok, I'll stop insulting Access :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, +1.